# Язык dart компилируется в JavaScript точно такой же как и TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dart

Наткнулся на [AngularDart](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular), который написан на гугловском языке `Dart`. И мне вот стало интересно в такой же `JavaScript` код он компилируется `TypeScript`?

В вики написано, что язык разрабатывался как альтернатива `JavaScript`

> Dart — язык программирования, созданный Google. Dart позиционируется в
>   качестве замены/альтернативы JavaScript. Один из разработчиков языка
>   Марк Миллер (Mark S. Miller) написал, что JavaScript «имеет
>   фундаментальные изъяны»[2](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dart) («Javascript has fundamental flaws…»),
>   которые невозможно исправить. Поэтому и был создан Dart.

[wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dart).

В то время, как `TypeScript` делался, как оболочка над `JavaScript` с типами.

`Dart` тоже сейчас компилится в `JavaScript`.

И вот у меня возник вопрос:

а есть ли в итоге отличия между скомпилируемыми кодами этих 2 ух языков? Ведь `Dart`(теоретически) может делать код ближе настольными языкам программирования, автоматически искореняя возможность потери контекстов через бинды и генеря проверки типов непосредственно в функциях `JavaScript`. Это предположение я делаю на основании почвы по которым данный язык родился на свет.

**UPD**

Потестил вот такой пример:

```
class AppComponent{
    String test1='1';

      AppComponent(){
        print('Test');
        test0(test);
        print(test1);
      }

    test0(Function func){
      print('0');
      func('123');
    }

    test(String t){
      print('1');
      test1=t;
    }
}
```

По идее вот такой в TypeScript должен отвалиться с ошибкой что свойство не определено из-за потери контекста но в Dart контекст не потерялся => как-то по другому все компилиться.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92653/discussion-on-question-by-iluxa1810--dart---javascript--).

Answer (score 3):

Оба языка компилируются в JavaScript. Полученый код конечно может отличаться так как разные компиляторы/трансляторы каждый из которых со своей реализацией. Результат выполнения такого кода ожидается одинаковым - если сгенерированый JavaScript код коректен.
ИМХО: в контексте Angular советовал бы всё же смотреть в сторону TypeScript - больше информационой поддержки, шире комьюнити и т.д.. Dart гораздо менее популярен под веб фронтенд и как по мне "выстрелил" он во Flutter, но это уже другая история